# What could be the cause of excessive idle times (2 minutes) during Windows 10 boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

My PC boots for 2 minutes (from push of button, until at WinLogin) and I have no clue why.
What have I already done:

- Disabled all non-Microsoft services in msconfig
- Booted Into Safe Mode (issue not present in safe-mode)
- Boot Traced using `xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags BASE-DIAG-LATENCY`
- Did Memory Diagnostics: Passed

#### System Information

- Make/Mode: Dell XPS 8930
- CPU: Intel Core i7-9700 @ 3.00Ghz
- RAM: 16GB (15.8 GB usable)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 2060
- Drives: 2 drives, both are SSDs

Image showing System Idle from 4 to 95 seconds:

[image]

I have no clue why it is waiting or if there's more to it that I don't see. Here is link to the [trace file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G8JQkrjb1a9lZQ4tl6G456-2NWZv8lTQ/view?usp=sharing).

The whole time the system is idle, it is on the Windows 10 circle dots loading screen, and I don't know how to fix this, or find a potentially broken service.

Comment: Use msconfig to do a diagnostic startup and check your startup time

Comment: @John If you mean Last BIOS Time from Task Manager it's 10.3 seconds

Comment: Try the msconfig suggestion.   Then add apps to see if you can determine what is taking the time

Comment: You can also get Windows 10 to VERBOSE messages as it Boots up (Winaero has a tool which might help.) https://winaero.com/enable-verbose-logon-messages-in-windows-10/

Comment: @kaveman to open msconfig use your start button and navigate to RUN open a RUN dialog box and type MSCONFIG.EXE.

Comment: @vssher; Verbose messages are not shown on boot, but after user logs in

Comment: @John Do I run WPA along with it? (Assuming yes), I also found two boot records for that drive in BIOS (when trying to do bootloader recovery), would that be a potential issue?

Comment: I do not know for sure (I have not run across that) but I would think the additional boot record might be an issue.

Comment: @John The person claimed there were two Windows Boot Managers before the issues happened and it might be because he moved the SSD from his old chassis to the new one (bought a prebuilt that had Windows on a M.2 which he wiped as uses as storage)

Comment: I ran MSCONFIG on my machines and only 1 boot record. No other issue in MSCONFIG startup and NO delays.

Comment: From your last comment, I think your setup is screwed up. Back up, format, install Windows fresh and it should be fine after that.

Comment: @John Lemme clarify, the duplicate boot entry exists in BIOS boot settings, not in msconfig, I tried both Windows Boot Managers, it boots into same OS with same delay.... I am trying to see if I can fix the issue without reinstall, because some software on it was a huge pain to setup (this PC is used for accounting, etc)

Comment: I am not sure how your computer is set up but it does seem that your setup is causing the slowdown. None in evidence here.